# FCM 'condition' field does not work

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I cannot manage to send a FCM message to be sent to multiple topics with the *condition* field. For some reason, even though FCM does not send my any error, my devices do not receive the message when using this field.

When I send this :

```
{
"to": "/topics/topic1",
"data": {
    "message": "test"
    }
}
```

the message is received, but I do not receive anything with this :

```
{
"condition": "'topic1' in topics",
"data": {
    "message": "test"
    }
}
```

even thought both message use the same topic name and both message return a success message from Firebase.

Comment: Have you found the solution? Kindly share if any.

Comment: I did not, sadly. I had to do it with other means. Wish you better luck.

Answer (score 0):

You must subscribe your devices to your topic, you can make rest service for subscribing. [Reference](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#manage_relationship_maps_for_multiple_app_instances) 
And when you want to send message you can provide title and body

Example:

```
{
  "message":{
        "condition": "'topic1' in topics",
         "data": {
           "message": "test"
       },
   "notification" : {
         "body" : "This is an FCM notification message!",
         "title" : "FCM Message",
      }
   }
}
```

With modeled response [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message)
    Topic HTTP POST request

```
Send to a single topic:

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
{
  "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
   }
}
Send to devices subscribed to topics "dogs" or "cats":

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
{
  "condition": "'dogs' in topics || 'cats' in topics",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
   }
}
Topic HTTP response

//Success example:
{
  "message_id": "1023456"
}

//failure example:
{
  "error": "TopicsMessageRateExceeded"
}
```

I made it with java RestTemplate and exchanging response.

Comment: My devices are already subscribed to the topic, else i wouldnt receive anything in the first case. My problem is that I do not receive anything when sending a message with "condition", even though I receive normally when using the "to"